# Where can I find legacy GTX 1050 ti Drivers?

Tags: display-driver

I have a GTX 1050 ti that I'm trying to install drivers for on Windows 7 64, however all drivers from 2019 onward require SHA-2 windows updates. I realize the logical solution would be to simply manually install the SHA-2 updates, but I can't because my Windows Update won't work due to a missing Services Plug-In. It's really a long story, but trust me when I say that damage is irreversible.

The only chance I have to get this 1050 ti operational is to locate some legacy drivers prior to the SHA-2 update requirement. That means 2016-2018. I've been to hell and back on the internet trying to locate some, but no dice. If anyone has some, or knows where I can find them, I would greatly appreciate it.

2016-2018 GTX 1050 ti drivers for Windows 7 64.

Comment: https://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/110597/en-us

Comment: A link to a driver doesn’t make an acceptable answer

Comment: It does if it's the answer I was looking for.